# Printing specific items with awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to print the second part of a comma delimited string `28213`. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
file="4646484726,28213,93951656,Jameson Booker,10000043,Domain,60008494,Amarr VIII (Oris) - Emperor Family Academy,10,True,583000.0,100,71.0,2016-10-04 13:49:51.000,0,1,60618962,90,False,30002187,Amarr,7688312.5,"
echo "$file"|sed s/,/\\n/g | awk '{print $2}'
```

I understand that `sed` is splitting the string into chunks by comma, and that `awk` is then returning only strings with spaces in them so `Jameson Booker` returns `Booker`, but I do not know how to split and return values for the entire line, not just the comma separated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk column matching doesn't work across multiple lines, which you're creating by inserting a line break. It works on whitespace based columns by default. Replace the comma with a space, not a line break.

```
echo "$file"|sed 's/,/ /g' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Or split on a comma by specifying the delimiter:

```
echo "$file"| awk -F',' '{print $2}'
```